# Yolov2 Compiling and Training: Problems on Windows 10

Tags: yolo, darknet

I have been having issues setting up Darknet. I will be using yolov2 to detect cerebral microbleeds for a neuroscience project. After battling Darknet for a few days, I managed to install it and successfully download the train, test and validation Pascal VOC data by using the below general configuration/set up:

- Cmake-GUI 3.2 (binary distributions, not source)
- MSVS 2019
- CUDA 11.1
- cuDNN 8.0.5
- OpenCV 4.2.0

I always get an error when running `darknet.exe detector train data/voc.data yolo-voc.2.0.cfg darknet19_448.conv.23` in cmd:

**'darknet.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file**

I cannot seem to understand the reason why.

In addition, when following the pjreddie instructions to modify cfg for Pascal Data:

```
classes= 20
train = /train.txt
valid = 2007_test.txt
names = data/voc.names
backup = backup
```

I change the Notepad file and all / to backslash, does that make a difference?

Could anyone shed some light as to how to successfully train the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's a generic error when you are trying to execute a program that is not in your current directory or not defined in PATH variable.

try adding the path to the darknet.exe file in your path variable:

\darknet\build\darknet\x64\